# java log4j - log to both category and root logger

Tags: java, log4j

I've got the following problem - This is my log4j config file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout, R
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=logs/example.log

log4j.category.A3=, A3
log4j.appender.A3=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A3.File=logs/A3.log
```

And this is my java code:

```
final static private Logger loggerA3 = Logger.getLogger("A3");
loggerA3.info("abcd");
```

Now, the `abcd` string appears in both `example.log` and `A3.log`, but I only want it to appear in `A3.log`, what should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please add the following line in log4j config file

```
log4j.additivity.A3=false
```

This will ensure that log is not appended to root logger